# Magento 2.2.7 - how to set 3 products i row instead of 4 in grid

Tags: luma-theme, magento2.2.7

How to set 3 products per row instead of 4 ?

[image]

Comment: Check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244924/magento-2-catalog-page-changing-number-of-items-per-row

Comment: thanks!
this works.
now, how to resize image on grid. i want a little bigger image

Comment: @RaulBaričević You can add a new question with a brief for your image resize in grid question.

Answer (score 0):

Change style in `_listing.less` in `Magento_Catalog\web\css\source\module` path

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__l) {
  .products-grid {
      .product-item {
          width: 100%/5;
      }
   }
}
```

to

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__l) {
    .page-products.page-layout-2columns-left,
    .page-products.page-layout-2columns-right {
        .products-grid .product-item {
            width: 100%/3;
        }
    }
}
```